# After Enabling SSL magento still loads default Javascript and CSS files with unsecure URLs

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

I enabled SSL in magento through following system configuration settings:

> System > Configuration > General > Web > Secure > Use Secure URLs in Frontend > Yes
>
> System > Configuration > General > Web > Secure > Use Secure URLs in Admin > Yes
>
> System > Configuration > General > Web > Secure > Offloader header > SSL_OFFLOADED
>
> System > Configuration > General > Web > Secure >  Base JavaScript URL > {{secure_base_url}}js/

Above setting completely breaks the frontend and gives the error `Blocked loading mixed active content` because all the Javascript and CSS files are being loaded through unsecure URLs using `http`. My `{{secure_base_url}}` is having `https` and a trailing slash.

These settings also leave the admin panel inaccessible as it gives the error `"This page is not redirecting properly"` when accessing backend.

**I am aware, similar questions have been asked here before and I tried all the solutions, but none of it is working.**

I can make it work temporarily by forcefully changing unsecure URLs to secure ones. But this is not the best way. Ideally, when the request is on https, Magento automatically takes the secure Javascript and CSS URLs.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Please also update

> System > Configuration > General > Web > Unsecure > Base URL

It should be `https://www.example.com/`
And add this code in .htaccess

```
#enable website to run https 
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And flush your Magento cache. For `"Blocked loading mixed active content"` open firebug console, it will tell which file is causing this error. If you are using static URL then you need to change it manually
from `http://` to  `https://` for more information on this [visit here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: That's my question. There is no point in changing the unsecure URLs to forcefully take secure URLs.  Doesn't magento handle this dynamically ? And there is no static URL in my store. The default magento JS files are being loaded over http. Also what about the admin panel error ?

Comment: And after changing the unsecure base url to https, the frontend started throwing error  - The page isn’t redirecting properly on frontend too.

Comment: You need to set a permanent redirect from HTTP to HTTPS from htaccess

Comment: Can you update your answer with the Htaccess settingS ?

Comment: @ReenaParekh I am working on the same task at this time. We change  unsecure URLs because if anywhere if system is using it then it will not break the page

Comment: this works but it's making me cringe as the unsecure is forcefully set to use the secure URL. This leads to loading unsecure JS and CSS files on secure connection. Which is basically the same solution that I mentioned in my question in last paragraph earlier. I am looking for what is causing this issue and trying to make it work dynamically, which ideally it should. Anyway, thanks for inputs. +1 from me.

Comment: @ReenaParekh yes, we're having the same problem, and the solution by Arunendra seems like a guesswork-hack, not a knowledgeable instruction.